# Exception when run Serenity tests on Jenkins in Seelnium grid

Tags: selenium, jenkins, grid

I run tests on my locale machine (not in grid), and it works. However, when I run on Jenkins, on Linux server in selenium grid, I have strange error:

> net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: The following error occurred: Expected condition failed: waiting for core.common.utils.WebDriverUtil$$Lambda$195/1333459330@4f5c82fa (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
>   Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
>   System info: host: 'fr-woqa01', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade
>       at net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException.detachedCopyOf(SerenityManagedException.java:21)
>       at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(StepInterceptor.java:419)
>       at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(StepInterceptor.java:151)
>       at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(StepInterceptor.java:138)
>       at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(StepInterceptor.java:69)
>       at serenity.steps.HomePageSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c60d4147.openPage()
>       at jbehave.scenariosteps.LoginPageScenario.navigateToPage(LoginPageScenario.java:26)
>       (reflection-invoke)
>       at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:733)
>       at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$FineSoFar.run(PerformableTree.java:346)

I run test using command:

```
-pl ui verify -Dstory.file.name=${story_name} -Denv.config.file=qa.properties  -Dwebdriver.remote.url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub -Dwebdriver.remote.driver=chrome -Dwebdriver.remote.os=LINUX -Dchrome.switches="--no-sandbox,--ignore-certificate-errors,--homepage=about:blank,--no-first-run, --disable-gpu, --disable-impl-side-painting, --disable-gpu-sandbox, --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas, --disable-accelerated-jpeg-decoding, --test-type=ui"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells serenity cannot talk to webdriver. Which could be either due to chromedriver not avaliable on the jenkins slave/jenkins machine or chrome itself not installed on the jenkins machine.

Run these commands on to check if chrome /chrome driver is installed on jenkins machine

which chromedriver
which google-chrome

Comment: I solved issue. I used WebDriver instead to use RemoteWebDriver

Comment: If using remotewebdriver in the code, then selenium server should be running